# Facebook iFrame page tab form POST submit opens a new page

Tags: facebook, forms, post, iframe, submit

I'm building a small app has a simple form to submit. I'm using iFrame tab for a Page on Facebook, as they just made it possible:
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/462

I get the page loading nicely in the Page tab, but the form submit doesn't open the result page in the iFrame but in the full window, thus getting out of Facebook. The form action is pointing to my server.

This worked fine when testing the app in the full Facebook canvas, the submit opened the result page to the iFrame. The problem is only with the Page tab.

I tried this:http://developers.facebook.com/docs/canvas/post/
but it doesn't allow me to put an iFrame after the form:
*"HTML error while rendering tag "iframe": iframes forbidden by flavor TabFBMLFlavor"*

I'm working on a tight schedule and would really appreciate some help! :) I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but can't get my head around this one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried switching the 'Page Tab Type' from FBML to iframe under Edit Settings > Facebook Integration > Page Tabs? Worked for me.

Comment: I didn't find this setting. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

php code

```
foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $value) {   
    $value = addslashes($value);
    $value = strip_tags($value);   
    if($value != ""){$requestnumber ++;}   
    $urlaccess .= $key ."=". $value."&";   
}


< form action=submit.php?< ?=$urlaccess?> method=post>
...
...
...
< /form>
```